# Is there something like "has_one :through (from Rails)" in Yii Framework?

Tags: activerecord, relationship, yii, has-many-through

I had the following tables:

```
manufacturers
* id
* name
* description

types
* id
* name
* description
* manufacturer_id

cars
* id
* title
* description
* type_id
```

Now my problem is, I want to list the cars with types and manufacurers, e.g:

```
* Some Car, Fiat Punto
* Another Car, Ferrari F1
```

...

In rails i can set the manufacturer relation with sth. like this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  has_one :manufacturer, :through => :type
end
```

Is this also possible in Yii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Yii 1.1.7 (I believe), 'through' support exists in relational active record now.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the "relations" function to accomplish things like that. The best page to get introduced would be the one about the ActiveRecord which you can find [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

Since the relationship between Cars is a one to many the type would be "HAS_MANY".

For example (assuming you have a Car and a Manufacturer model):

Car:

```
public function relations()
{
   return array('manufacturer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Manufacturer', 'manufacturerId'));
}
```

Manufacturer:

```
public function relations()
{
   return array('cars' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Car', 'manufacturerId'));
}
```

You can then fetch an array of cars for a manufacturer through:

```
foreach($oManufacturer->cars as $oManufacturer)
   echo $oManufacturer->name;
```

For a car:

```
    echo $oCar->manufacturer->name;
```

This assumes that both tables have the manufacturerId fied.
Hope that helps :)

edit: You are not obligated to define the relation in both models. If for example you don't need a manufacturer from a car then it's perfectly okay to not define the relations function there.

Comment: Thanks. That's also my current solution (to insert the manufacturer_id in types and cars). But is it possible to create the relations without a manufacturer_id in the cars table?

Comment: The only other solution I can see is to create a mapping table that holds carId <> manufacturerId entries. It would be slightly more work as you'd have to do a findByAttributes to locate either the cars or the manufacturer first and link them to the actual objects.